# AJAX parse + Yahoo YQL returning no results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yql

I'm working on a script that gets all the `<table>` elements from an external website by going through Yahoo's YQL. This has worked fine recently, but it stopped working as of today. I'm not entirely sure why, all websites used to work with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var container = $('#target');
    function doAjax(url) {
        if (url.match('^http')) {
            $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" 
            + "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" 
            + encodeURIComponent(url) 
            + "%22&format=xml'&callback=?", 
            function (data) {
                if (data.results[0]) {
                    var fullResponse = $(filterData(data.results[0])),
                        justTable = fullResponse.find("body");
                    container.append(justTable);
                } else {
                    var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
                    container.html(errormsg);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#target').load(url);
        }
    }
    function filterData(data) {
        data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g, '');
        data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/, '');
        data = data.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, '');
        return data;
    }
    doAjax('http://www.google.com');
});
</script>
```

I changed the url to google and changed it to find the `<body>` tag instead of `<table>` tags to better show its not working. I looked at the URL that it's requesting and it's not showing any content. Not sure what the problem is though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was that YQL was down? I just tested it again and it worked out fine. I wish they would tell us in the future if an outage occurred.

Comment: following [@yql](http://twitter.com/yql) on Twitter is helpful. It doesn't seem to have a lot of the short-term outages, but if there are any more general problems or upgrades, the Twitter channel seems to be helpful. Also, you should probably mark your own answer as accepted here, so this question is marked as completed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the "external website" you have crawled has structural changes?
When it has worked before and now not anymore, then my tip is that the site structure has changed.

Comment: Yes... Like I said, I changed the code above to find the `<body>` tag of google and display it's content. And I highly doubt google decided to get rid of the body tag.